# DVTProvisioningProfileManager: Failed to load profile "/Users/apple/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/Archive"

Tags: flutter

I can run the flutter build ios command .and use XCode to run the app .just can't run flutter code in vs code . will show this error.

DVTProvisioningProfileManager: Failed to load profile "/Users/apple/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/Archive" (Error Domain=DVTProvisioningProfileSourceErrorDomain Code=0 "No provisioning profile provider found for profile "/Users/apple/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/Archive"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No provisioning profile provider found for profile "/Users/apple/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/Archive".})